# Infinite current carrying wire, moving parallel to it's current flow direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, reference-frames, acceleration, electric-current

At $t=0$ current flows in an infinite wire, and creates a magnetic field, after sometime the infinite wire begins to accelerate(only the wire wile $I$ remains constant), in a direction parallel to the current flow, if I imagine myself as the observer on a fixed point, what should I see?

Is there a magnetic field? Is there current flow? Since the wire itself is now moving in the same direction of the current flow.

My initial thought:

At point P, I would observe the wire moving, therefore, all the other variables would move with it as well. The current $I$ and the magnetic field $B$, however,

**My confusion:**

If the wire is moving, is the current moving with the wire? Or is it independent of the wire's motion(since it's parallel to the current flow direction)? 
It's like imagining an infinite pipe carrying water, if I do the exact same thing, it seems like the water is independent of the pipe's motion.

If the wire's motion was perpendicular(rather than parallel) to the current flow it's easier to imagine it.

Comment: Is the wire accelerating or the current in the wire?

Comment: What do you think? Please show your attempt to solve your own problem. What difficulty are you having?

Comment: @JohnathanGross         Please check https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355425/infinite-current-carrying-wire-moving-parallel-to-its-current-flow More details there(same user, forgot my old account's information now recovered).

Comment: @sammygerbil I attempted it here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355425/infinite-current-carrying-wire-moving-parallel-to-its-current-flow (I'm the same user, forgot my old account's information now recovered) and couldn't delete this account...

Comment: *Is the current moving with the wire?* The current is the motion of the electrons within the wire. It is part of the wire.